# Number manipulation using REGEX

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression for you out there.

I need a regular expression that will do the following. 
1)  Decimal literal must include a whole number and a fraction. For example .34 must be written as 0.34. The number 4 must be written as 4.0.
2)  Unnecessary leading and trailing zeros should be avoided. For example: 0.0, 123.01, 123003.0, are all legal but 00.0, 0.00, 002334, 1.23.00 are not.

In essence, I need a regex to chop off leading 0s and trailing zeros in a floating point number. There should be a minimum of one number to the left of the decimal point, for example 0.1 rather than .1

Comment: What's the programming language you're using? It may have some more appropriate methods.

Comment: I have tried (-?\d*\.?\d?) but it doesn't seem to be giving me the output I would expect. I'm knew to regex's and am not sure how to determine 0s and chop.

Comment: Is this really a regex problem or a number formatting problem?

Comment: the regex you wrote makes no sense to one of your requirements. the first one is easy but the second one could be painful.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase. I need to truncate leading 0s and trailing 0s on a floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

This one seems to work, the only problem was for 0.0, that's why i added the `|(0\.0)` at the end of the sentence because i didn't find something better.

```
(-?[1-9]{1}\d+\.{1}\d*)|(0\.0)
```

I also have a link for you to try this solution or find your own with regexr :

http://regexr.com/39l9i

Hope it has been usefull.

Comment: Doesn't match `1.0` but match `10.` that is not wanted.

Comment: That is close but not quite there. It should help me get on the right track

Comment: maybe the second part change to `0\.\d+`? and `{1}` is not necessary. and it's not truncating `0`s. maybe `(-?[1-9]\d*\.\d+(?!0))|(0\.\d+(?!0))`? not tested.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr your solution seems to be the good one, i tested it on regexr and it seems right =)

Comment: HuStmpHrr if you move this from the comment to an answer I will mark you correct